# How to spy on a function that is also referenced by a property

Tags: angularjs, testing, jasmine, spy, spyon

Given this code:

```
function getAnimal(type, color) {
    console.log('blub'); // this is triggered when executing the test
}
this.getAnimal = getAnimal;
```

and this testing code:

```
describe('getAnimal()', function() {
    it('should get an animal based on type and color', function() {
        spyOn(this.AnimalService, 'getAnimal');
        this.AnimalService.getAnimal();

        expect(this.AnimalService.getAnimal).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
});
```

But I get this error message:
*Expected spy function(){return i} to have been called.*

So I guess only the `this.getAnimal = getAnimal` is spied, but not the function. How can I fix this?

Answer (score -1):

For such cases you can use `rewire`. Using `rewire` you can replace the function/variables inside any module that are not exported

Comment: Please give an example. Rewire seems not to be part of Jasmine itself?

Comment: @GarfieldKlon Search on google will give you lot of details. Please check https://www.npmjs.com/package/rewire